# Passing JSON Objects to web service through POSTMAN

Tags: java, json, postman

Hi i am new to JSON and used POSTMAN to post a JSON Object to a java web service
The json object is as follows.

```
{"fname":"Syslog_DuraDiagnost_Xray and Imaging_20141029"}
```

My web service is something like this

```
public class JerseyParse {
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response ParseObj(JSONObject input )throws IOException {
        try
        {

        String filename=input.getString("fname");
        System.out.println(filename);
        }
        catch( Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
         }
      }
    }
```

The web service is throwing an exception something like this

```
2015-07-22T16:35:09.275+0530|Severe: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "fname" (Class org.json.JSONObject), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@d1ac74; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: org.json.JSONObject["fname"])
```

Please tell me if i have gone wrong. . .

Comment: Sundeep, how did you configure POSTMAN for sending such query ?

Comment: Because of this part of the exception "UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "fname"" I believe the request is indeed  being processed on the server.  I'm not too familiar with Java but maybe you could try input = {"fname":"Syslog_DuraDiagnost_Xray and Imaging_20141029"}.

Comment: Thank you for your response. POSTMAN is just a browser plugin to test REST api. I did not configure it.  I also tried your answer, i got a new exception "JSONObject should contain character '{' at line 1 column 1. So input should be some thing of the form {JSONdata}